# Prevent access to unwanted default URLs in Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

My project consists of areas which all have a default Index action.
This action, though, I want  only to be accessible with the following URL pattern:

```
/{area}/
```

Its controller is `DefaultController` and the action name is `Index`.
Right now I seem to be able to access this index action with both the following URLs:

`/import/Default` and `/import/Default/Index`. Only `/import` or `/import/` should be a valid URL in this example case.

Is there any way to prevent this?

**ImportAreaRegistration.cs**

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
{
   context.MapRoute(
         name: "Import_default",
         url: "import/{controller}/{action}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index" },
         namespaces: new string[] { "Tax.Areas.Import.Controllers" }
   );
}
```

**DefaultController.cs**

```
namespace Tax.Areas.Import.Controllers
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    [RouteArea("import")]
    public class DefaultController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent unwanted routes using the `IgnoreRoute` extension method on the `RouteCollection`. It is important that this step be done *before* you register your area routes so they are executed in the proper order.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        // Ignore unwanted routes first
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{area}/Default");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{area}/Default/Index");

        // Then register your areas (move this line here from Global.asax)
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can ignore routes within the `RegisterArea` method by doing the following:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
{
    context.Routes.Add(new Route("import/Default", new StopRoutingHandler()));
    context.Routes.Add(new Route("import/Default/Index", new StopRoutingHandler()));

    context.MapRoute(
        name: "Import_default",
        url: "import/{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index" },
        namespaces: new string[] { "Tax.Areas.Import.Controllers" }
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But will I have to type these two lines for all my areas? Is there a more dynamic way?

Comment: You can use placeholders in the URL if all of your areas use the same default settings, such as `{area}/Default/Index`. Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696224/asp-net-mvc-ignoreroute-inside-an-area) to see how you can register ignore routes inside the Area.

Comment: I tried adding `routes.IgnoreRoute("{area}/Default");` in the `RouteConfig` but the website still doesn't ignore that route. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: My example is working exactly as I have above. Did you put `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()` *after* your `IgnoreRoute` statements and *before* your default route? And did you ensure you remove the `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()` line from your `Global.asax`?

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! Sorry, I missed that part about moving out `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()` from `Global.asax` :)